# How to determine whether iOS device is connected to desktop computer (and iTunes)

Tags: iphone, ios, itunes

Is there way to determine whether an iOS device is connected to a desktop computer using USB cable and it is listed on iTunes.

Comment: Do you want to detect from Mac OS X when an iOS device is connected to computer/laptop?  Or do you want to detect from an app running on iOS device when it connected to a computer?

Comment: I want to detect from an app running on iOS device.

Comment: Why would your app need to know if it's connected to a computer? What feature will your app provide if connected to a computer? Plus there's no API to iTunes in iOS Frameworks.

Comment: As you know, iOS app can share files with iTunes thru iTunes File Sharing. My customer wants some feature which work only when iOS device is connected to iTunes. I think I should close this question.

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can be notified of such events using The  [**External Accessory framework**.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ExternalAccessoryPT/Articles/MonitoringEvents.html)

"It is capable of sending notifications whenever a hardware accessory is connected or disconnected. Although it is capable, it does not do so automatically. Your application must specifically request that notifications be generated by calling the registerForLocalNotifications method of the `EAAccessoryManager` class. When an accessory is connected, authenticated, and ready to interact with your application, the framework sends an `EAAccessoryDidConnectNotification` notification. When an accessory is disconnected, it sends an `EAAccessoryDidDisconnectNotification` notification. You can register to receive these notifications using the default `NSNotificationCenter`, and both notifications include information about which accessory was affected."

Comment: I tested with EADemo provided by Apple and it is for accessories. It does not work when iOS device is connected to Desktop computer. Anyway, thanks for your time.