# OSX-iOS: Detect iOS device connection type (wired/wireless)

Tags: objective-c, ios, macos, iphone-privateapi

I actually use **MobileDevice.framework** to know if a device is connected, but I want to differentiate devices by connection type (wired/wireless).

So how to detect which device is connected with USB and other wirelessly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at these questions:

[How to determine whether iOS device is connected to desktop computer (and iTunes)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6161318/how-to-determine-whether-ios-device-is-connected-to-desktop-computer-and-itunes)

[An application to check iPhone connection with USB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7426258/an-application-to-check-iphone-connection-with-usb)

[USB detection in jailbreak ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12040200/usb-detection-in-jailbreak-ios)

Also, I would recommend to take a look at **IOKit.framekwork**. It has a lot of stuff related to USB.